# 12.04 HWES OEM won't upgrade, new HP455 laptop

Tags: oem

Can some one please help, I have a new laptop a HP455 from ebuyer and its throwing up the following complains when trying to install the security and hardware support package in update manager:

```
installArchives() failed: 
Extract templates from packages: 48%%
Extract templates from packages: 96%%
Extract templates from packages: 100%%

Extract templates from packages: 48%%
Extract templates from packages: 96%%
Extract templates from packages: 100%%

Extract templates from packages: 48%%
Extract templates from packages: 96%%
Extract templates from packages: 100%%

Extract templates from packages: 48%%
Extract templates from packages: 96%%
Extract templates from packages: 100%%
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%%
(Reading database ... 10%%
(Reading database ... 15%%
(Reading database ... 20%%
(Reading database ... 25%%
(Reading database ... 30%%
(Reading database ... 35%%
(Reading database ... 40%%
(Reading database ... 45%%
(Reading database ... 50%%
(Reading database ... 55%%
(Reading database ... 60%%
(Reading database ... 65%%
(Reading database ... 70%%
(Reading database ... 75%%
(Reading database ... 80%%
(Reading database ... 85%%
(Reading database ... 90%%
(Reading database ... 95%%
(Reading database ... 100%%
(Reading database ... 185836 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking fglrx-core (from .../fglrx-core_1%%3a14.201-0ubuntu2wataugafour2_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx-core_1%%3a14.201-0ubuntu2wataugafour2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/acpi/fglrx-powermode.sh', which is also in package fglrx 2:14.201-0ubuntu1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx-core_1%%3a14.201-0ubuntu2wataugafour2_amd64.deb
Error in function: 
SystemError: E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am at a bit of a loss with this and wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Add your edit about solving this as an answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have since solved this problem.

If you look in the proprietary drivers list, you will see a driver that is enabled that prevents loading of invalid `fglrx` drivers.

If you deactivate this, then reboot, the *Security and Hardware support* package will install.